# Delphi Chromium, Javascript Button press

Tags: javascript, delphi, click, chromium

i am trying to press a button in javascript using chromium.

In twebbroswer i am using

```
WebBrowser1.OleObject.document.GetElementByID('uidPasswordLogon').Click;
```

With Chromium i am using

```
code := 'document.getElementById("uidPasswordLogon").click()' ;
chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript (code, '', 0);
```

but it doesn´t work.

I have managed to complete Javascript fields by using

```
chromium1.Browser.MainFrame.ExecuteJavaScript('document.all("logonuidfield").value="'+User_Email.Text+'";', '', 0);
```

but for the clicks it just doesn´t work. Any suggestions? :D

Answer (score 2):

If you are using DCEF3 version of TChromiumEmbed then you need address focused frame. Do't be scared from the "about:blank", it works on active document too.

```
procedure TForm1.executeChromeJavascript(javascript: string);
begin
  if crm.Browser <> nil then
    crm.Browser.FocusedFrame.ExecuteJavaScript(
      javascript, 'about:blank', 0);
end;
```